# Angular 4 X-editable form value does not change when content is updated

Tags: angular, x-editable

As I have tried to explain the situation in the title, I am having a problem with `jQuery X-editable` library in `Angular 4`.

I have a `view` as below:

**model.html**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();" editableToggle="#editable{{selectedModel.id}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
<div id="editable{{selectedModel.id}}" class="editable-textarea" editable type="textarea" url="/api/model-info" name="info" pk="{{selectedModel.id}}">
    {{selectedModel.info}}
</div>
```

As you can see, I had to create 2 different directives, for some reason, called `editableToggle` and `editable`. That may be the subject of another question. For this problem, here is the structures of these directives.

**editable-toggle.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[editableToggle]'
})
export class EditableToggleDirective {
    @Input() editableToggle: string;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

    @HostListener('click') onClick(){
        $(this.editableToggle).editable('toggle');
    }
}
```

**editable.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[editable]' })
export class EditableDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() type: string;
    @Input() url: string;
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() pk: number;

    directive: any;

    constructor(el: ElementRef){
        this.directive = $(el.nativeElement);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

        var options = {
            type: this.type,
            url: this.url,
            name: this.name,
            pk: this.pk,
            rows: 10,
            originalTitle: 'Title',
            toggle: 'manual',
            emptytext: 'Empty',
            ajaxOptions: {
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            params: function (params) {
                params._token = token;
                return params;
            }
        };

        this.directive.editable(options);
    }
}
```

At first, x-editable just works fine with initially selected model. My problem here is that, when I change the `selectedModel` with different ID and Info, even though the HTML values are changed correctly, the info of the initial model is written in the x-editable pop-up form, not the selected one's.

I tried to explain the situation as basic as possible. Correct me if I'm wrong or missing something with your comments please.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT: Created a plunker for this problem https://plnkr.co/edit/Moq3jUEbSCIS4HDO6jPq?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Add editable prefix to {{selectedModel.info}}